# How to loop over questions in Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

How can I loop over a list of questions with Web Speech API.  For example I want to ask a series of Yes or No questions and then handle the result differently if the answer is yes, and move on to the next question if the answer is no.

```
var questions = //array of five questions
function answerQuestions {
    for (i = 0; questions.length; i++) {
      if (askUser(questions[i]) {
          ///Do something if yes
      } else if ((i+1) === questions.length){
         //stop asking questions
      }
}
function askUser (question) {
    //instantiate Web Speech API
     //someinstance.speak(question)
 }
function say(m){   
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();   
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();    
    msg.voice = voices[10];     
    msg.voiceURI = "Google UK English Male";    
    msg.volume = 1;     
    msg.rate = 1;   
    msg.pitch = 1.4;    
    msg.text = m;   
    msg.lang = 'en-GB';     
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg); 
    msg.onend = function () {
        listenToAnswer()
    }
}
```

The issue is that it never will call listenToAnswer() and listen to the next user input.  Instead it just loops really quickly through the the for loop of questions.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The operations are asynchronous, so you can't use a plain `for` loop like that, it'll run all at once. Return `Promises` and `await` each asynchronous operation instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  I researched promises and it worked, but now it's calling listenToResponse before the question ends  


`async function pickQuestion (subject) {
    questionsOfSubject = questions[subject];
    for (i = 0; i < questionsOfSubject.length; i++){
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve (say("Would you like to read, " + questionsOfSubject[i].title));
        });
        var answer  = await listenToResponse();
        if (answer.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
            readQuestion()
            break;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

First, `say` needs to return a `Promise` that resolves once the speaking is done. That way, you can call `say()` and `await` it inside the `for` loop. Currently, you're constructing a `Promise` inside `pickQuestion`, but then you're resolving it *immediately* because you're calling its `resolve` right after the Promise is constructed. So, there's no time for anything asynchronous to be done.

Once `say` returns a `Promise`, you can avoid constructing another `Promise` inside the `for` loop, and simply await the `say` call:

```
function say(m){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();   
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();    
    msg.voice = voices[10];     
    msg.voiceURI = "Google UK English Male";    
    msg.volume = 1;     
    msg.rate = 1;   
    msg.pitch = 1.4;    
    msg.text = m;   
    msg.lang = 'en-GB';     
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg); 
    msg.onend = function () {
      resolve()
    }
  });
}

async function pickQuestion(subject) {
  const questionsOfSubject = questions[subject];
  for (let i = 0; i < questionsOfSubject.length; i++) {
    await say("Would you like to read, " + questionsOfSubject[i].title);
    const answer = await listenToResponse();
    if (answer.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
      readQuestion();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to declare new variables with `const` (or `let`) so as not to implicitly assign to window properties.